# Rest API code 400 "message":"Callout loop not allowed"

Tags: apex, rest-api, error, post

I tried to call Salesforce Api `/services/data/v54.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport` in order to create a service report but I got this error :

> the status code returned was not expected: 400 Bad Request
> [{"actionName":"createServiceReport","errors":[{"statusCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION","message":"Callout
> loop not
> allowed","fields":[]}],"isSuccess":false,"outputValues":null}]

I used the same request on workbench and it works !

code :

```
public class AP001_ServiceReport implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public List<Id> contrList;
    public AP001_ServiceReport(List<Id> controleIds){
        contrList = controleIds;
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void generateBulkServiceReports(List<List<string>> controleIds){
        list<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        for(List<string> id : controleIds){
            ids=id.clone();
        }
        System.debug('ff '+controleIds);
        System.debug('ff '+ids);
        System.enqueueJob(new AP001_ServiceReport(ids));
    }


    public static void callApi(String entityId , String templateId){
        System.debug('entityId: '+entityId);
        System.debug('templateId: '+templateId);
        String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
            String url = salesforceHost + '/services/data/v54.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport';
        // Create HTTP request
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');

        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        
        String jsonString = JSON.serialize(new Map<String,Object> {
            'inputs' => new List<Object> {
                new Map<String,Object> {
                    'entityId' => entityId,
                        'templateId' => templateId   
                        }
            }
        });
        // Set the body as a JSON object
        request.setBody(jsonString);
        System.debug('body '+request.getBody());
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                         response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus()+' '+response.getBody());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        //your code including the callout
        System.debug('ffddh33 '+contrList);
        List<Chantier__c> controleList = [select id ,(select id,Subject,recordTYpe.name,WorkTypeId from OrdresExecution__r),(select id,WorkTypeId from Service_Appointments__r) from Chantier__c where id IN :contrList];
        map<String,WorkType> mapWorkType = new  map<String,WorkType>([select id , ServiceReportTemplateId from WorkType]);
        
        for(Chantier__c controle : controleList ){
            for(WorkOrder wo : controle.OrdresExecution__r){
                if(wo.Subject.contains('Téléphone')){
                    callApi(wo.id,mapWorkType.get(wo.WorkTypeId).ServiceReportTemplateId);
                }else{
                    if(controle.Service_Appointments__r[0]!= null){
                        callApi(controle.Service_Appointments__r[0].id,mapWorkType.get(controle.Service_Appointments__r[0].WorkTypeId).ServiceReportTemplateId);   
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was caused by a before insert trigger . Thanks all !